# Module::Load: Find out whether a module failed to load because of error, or simply doesn't exist

Tags: perl

I want a module to dynamically load plugins using Module::Load. If there's no such plugin, it's OK, but *if* it is there and *fails* to load, I want to take action (e.g. give a warning, or even die).

A temporary solution looks like  `$@ !~ /^Couldn't locate /`, however, I don't find it bullet-proof. E.g. a module may require another module which is absent, or use Module::Load itself, or etc.

The `Module::Load` itself isn't that complicated after all, so I was even considering adding a package variable there (e.g. `$Module::Load::Absent`), but I'm not sure it makes sense.

So, the question: how do I tell `load`ing a missing module from loading a defective one?

Comment: Modules are required to return a true value when being loaded. Why not let a faulty plugin return zero when initialization fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to [`use Module::Load::Conditional`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Load/Conditional.html) instead. It has the ability to `check_install` and check `can_load` so you can find out if your module is installed and simply can't load.

```
use Carp;
use Module::Load::Conditional;

if ( check_install( module =>  'Data::Dumper' ) ) {
    if ( can_load( modules => { 'Data::Dumper' => undef } ) ) { # any version of Data::Dumper
        requires 'Data::Dumper'; # load Data::Dumper part of ::Conditional
    }
    else {
       carp 'can\'t load Data::Dumper';
    }
}
else {
    carp 'Data::Dumper not installed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
use Module::Load;

my $module = 'Data:Dumper';

if (load $module)
{
    # Success
}
else
{
    # Fail
}
```

Comment: But `load` raises an exception when it can't load a module for whatever reason. So this program will never reach the `#fail` branch.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if there's no such plugin you can iterate through @INC and check if the file that is supposed to contain the module exists, something like the following (untested of course :):

```
use File::Spec::Functions;

my $filename = catfile(split('::', $modulename)) . '.pm';
foreach my $path (@INC) {
    if ( -f catfile($path, $filename)) {
       # found it!
       last;
    }
}
```